# Define a function when given a graph with points (0,3),(2,5),(10,4),(6,2)

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization, scripting, education, mathematica-online

Define a function when you are given a graph with points (0,3),(2,5),(10,4),(6,2)

Comment: Is this about Wolfram Mathematica?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FindFormula`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html):

```
list = {{0, 3}, {2, 5}, {10, 4}, {6, 2}};

ClearAll[f]
f = FindFormula[list];

f[x]
```

> $  3. + 2.12083 x - 0.65 x^2 + 0.0447917 x^3$

```
f /@ list[[All, 1]]
```

> {3., 5., 4., 2.}

Alternatively, you can use [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html):

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 = Interpolation[list];
f2 /@ list[[All, 1]]
```

> {3, 5, 4, 2}